# Trying to connect my Bluetooth headphone to my PC

Tags: networking, sound, bluetooth, headphones

I need help. Everything goes fine, but when I want to connect my Bluetooth headphone it won't let me connect or it connects for a second and disconnects itself and like I have tried to pair and trust commands and it actually works out okay, but when I use the command to connect it instantly it gives me this error:

> Attempting to connect to MAC NUMBER
> Failed to connect: org .blue z .Error.Failed b r-connection-profile-unavailable

Comment: Which OS and version are you using? If you are using Linux, specify the distro name as well. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1498274/edit) and add the answer up there.